# Capturing the country by IP Address without using an API

Tags: apex, api, visualforce-component

I am developing a VF page in a customer portal and dynamically rendering a text inside the page based on the Guest user's country. Currently I have achieved this using the below endpoint.
http://ipinfo.io
Is there anyway of achieving this without using an API by considering two factors namely 'cost' and 'governor limit'?

Comment: much discussion about this on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206015/fastest-way-of-detecting-users-country)

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a free IPv4/IPv6 database, load the records in to a custom object, and then query for the IP address by range. Note that you must first normalize the IP addresses as 000.000.000.000 and 0000:0000:0000:0000 format in order to efficiently query records; IPv6 uses only the first 64 bits for public routing, so you don't need to store the second half. This should be perfectly possible, as the database for these routes are pretty small (a couple of thousand records).